# CodeIgniter htaccess file after migrate to online host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I developed a website using CI on localhost,
at the site root directory I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxxyyyzzz/index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxxyyyzzz/index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxxyyyzzz/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

where xxxyyyzzz is my website name, and I open it in browser: (127.0.0.1/xxxyyyzzz/SomeControllerName/SomeMethodName).

I migrate my site to public web host (ip = aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd)
how should I change the htaccess file?
I tried many solutions that I found on the web but the did not work...
Thanks!

Comment: if your domain is not pointing on the CI Root Directory 
`RewriteBase / xxxyyyzzz` else remove the CI Directory

Answer (score 0):

As tomexsans commented, your rewrite rules are `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxxyyyzzz/index.php?/$1 [L]` so if you are not using the subdirectory /xxxyyyzzz than you need to remove it. Also make sure you are changing your default path in the codeigniter `application/config/config.php` file. Sometimes I forget to change certain things when I upload to the live site, just dot your I's and cross your T's. (:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = '';
```